# 32feet.NET BluetoothListener In C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bluetooth

I have a windows application with version .net framework 4.7.2 and I need a Bluetooth listener for receive and save files were sending to this device by Bluetooth.

I using 32feet.NET and I was written this code :

but its have some problems. if another way recommended, please tell me. other wise please help me to solve current problems.

1. it was took so long when I reading stream bytes to write into file. and after written, It was wrong data written into file :(
2. how I can get extension of receiving file?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _bluetoothListener = new BluetoothListener(BluetoothService.ObexObjectPush);
    _listenerThread = new Thread(ListenForBluetoothRequests);
    _listenerThread.Start();
}

private void ListenForBluetoothRequests()
{
    _bluetoothListener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            _bluetoothListener.Pending();
            BluetoothClient client = _bluetoothListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();

            if (client != null)
            {
                // Handle the incoming file transfer
                HandleIncomingFile(client);

                // Close the client connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions, if any
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private void HandleIncomingFile(BluetoothClient client)
{
    // Customize the file save path as per your requirement
    string savePath = "C:\\BluetoothReceivedFiles\\";

    if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
    }

    Stream networkStream = client.GetStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;

    // Read the incoming file and save it
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(savePath, "ReceivedFile.txt")))
    {
        while ((bytesRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```